# AF_PACKET socket not receiving IPv6 packets

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6

I was trying to sniff network traffic using the AF_PACKET raw socket. I am able to get all IP/ARP packets, but I am unable to get any IPv6 packets at all. Is there anything I need to do to get IPv6 traffic?

```
   unsigned char buffer[65536];
   int sock_raw = socket( AF_PACKET , SOCK_RAW , htons(ETH_P_ALL)) ;

   if (sock_raw < 0)
   {
     perror("socket error!");
     return 1;
   }

   while (1)
   {
      struct sockaddr saddr;
      int saddr_size, data_size;

      data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw, buffer, 65536, 0, &saddr, (socklen_t *)&saddr_size);

      if (data_size >= 0)
      {
         ProcessPacket(buffer, data_size);
      }
   }
```

Comment: It might depend on what OS you are using. Windows? Linux? FreeBSD?  FreeDOS?

Comment: Is this a switched ethernet network? That would require you to set up port mirroring. If it is a Wi-Fi network, that would require you to be in monitor or promiscuous mode. Otherwise, you will only see broadcast, e.g. ARP, or traffic destined just for your host.

Comment: Is the interface in promiscuous mode?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I can see IPv6 traffic using tcpdump on the same interface, but not the program above. I have tried to put the interface to promiscuous mode without success.

Comment: My bad. IPv6 have different Ethernet protocol: ETH_P_IPV6 instead of ETH_P_IP, and I was only looking for the ETH_P_IP packets! Adding the case for ETH_P_IPv6 solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

My bad. IPv6 have different Ethernet protocol: ETH_P_IPV6 instead of ETH_P_IP, and I was only looking for the ETH_P_IP packets! Adding the case for ETH_P_IPv6 solved the issue!

Comment: Yes, IPv6 doesn't use ARP, and it doesn't have broadcast.